# iOS Reminders caldav file name

Tags: iphone, ios, caldav

Here's my current setup:

- Server with [radicale](http://radicale.org/) installed and configured
- Mail & reminders iOS account setup connecting to my server

With this setup, I'm able to add and sync calendars, contacts, and reminders from my server to my iPhone and various other devices. The iOS reminders app automatically displays the correct list names from the files on my server.  For example, the file named *Bills* on my server shows up in the Reminders app as list with the title *Bills*.  However, creating a new list directly in the reminders app creates a new file on my server that's name is a GUID.  For example, creating a  new list named *Fake* from my iPhone creates a file on my server named *0847796F-C35C-49BC-A41A-0C50E41F0266*.

The inconvenience is that I need to be home (due to firewall restrictions) and SSH into my server to find out or change the file name generated by iOS before I can add it in other applications, like Thunderbird.  Is there any way to force iOS to create files with names that match what I enter on the device itself instead of using a GUID?

Comment: Questions about electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones are off-topic (except when they interface with a computer). See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try asking on http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks @DavidPostill http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/176298/ios-reminders-caldav-file-name